# Angular typescript iterate over results returned from service call

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate over an "array" that's being returned from a result set in order to process the objects contained within.

I have tried various approaches including `data.forEach()`, `const myStuff = {...data}` and `for (let item of data) {}` in both the "success" function of the `.subscribe` and in the `processData` function, but in all cases I'm unable to extract the values desired.

DevTools reports the result to be `Array(51)` but it sure doesn't want to process like a typical Array.

```
  submitCarrierSearchForm = (): void => {
    this.carrierService
      .carrierGetCarrierListByOrgCode({
        organizationCode: this.searchForm
          .get('carrierSearch')
          ?.get('organizationCode')?.value
      })
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          // this.processData(data);
          console.log(data);
        },
        (error: unknown) => {
          console.log('Errors encountered: ', error);
        },
      );
  };

  processData(carriers: Carrier): void {
    console.log('coming from data: ', carriers);
  }
```

Errors vary, including:
Property 'forEach' doesn't exist on type (lists all properties of the object) when using

```
    const stuff = { ...carriers };

    stuff.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element.carrierName);
    });
```

No doubt, it's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: 1. What does `console.log(data)` print? 2 Is the response same for the same request?

Comment: Your data might not fit the type Carrier. Does data actually contain Carrier types as elements of the array?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you declare 1 item in stead of an array of items:

maybe try this:

```
  processData(carriers: Carrier[]): void {
    console.log('coming from data: ', carriers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an error in the return type of the API which was preventing the object from actually being an array. Once the return type was corrected, all the "normal" ways of manipulating an array worked as expected.